# How can I exit/leave a party in the main menus?

Tags: diablo-iii

When in the main menu screen, is there a way to leave or disband the party without logging out? I can't find any such options (as party leader or otherwise).

[image: leaving a party]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your character. You will have the option to "Leave Party" whether you are the party leader or not.

[image: Leave Party]