# In Diablo 3 how to start single player mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

What I mean by single player mode is I want to create game and don't allow others to join.

Sometimes there are things I wanna do alone like finding Kanai's cube. Other people keep on wanting to do something else.

I know I can join game. There's an option for that. But how to create game? Single player game?

Comment: not duplicate. That one presumes that the player already knows how to create single player games. And then prevent friends from joining. I want to create single player games.

Comment: no body plays diablo 3 anymore isn't it. it's just not popular

Comment: This question: How do I stop random people from joining. Other question: How do I stop my friends from quick joining. Similar questions, ***but not duplicates***.

Comment: Creating a single player game is no different than creating any other game.  The other question has it correct, if you turn off auto join and make a game, then no one will ever join your game, effectively making it single player.

Comment: If its no different to the other answer, why did you use the other answer as *step 2*, in a 4 step solution? "No different", to me, implys that there would not be *any* steps after it.

Comment: @timelord because the other 3 steps are blindingly obvious to anyone whose played Diablo 3 people don't even think about it.

Comment: It's the reason why so many people first assumed he just wanted what the other question answered.

Comment: I haven't played diablo 3 for a very long time. So I forget how to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Single player game in 4 easy steps:

1. [Make sure you are not in a party](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67795/how-can-i-exit-leave-a-party-in-the-main-menus).
2. [Make sure no one can join the game you make without permission.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63738/how-do-you-prevent-friends-from-joining-your-game)
3. Click on game settings to pick your game mode and difficulty level.  Make sure it will be a PRIVATE game, not public.
4. Click on the big Start Game button.  If you see join game instead of start game, then go back to step 3 and confirm its a private game.

[image: teh buttonz]

Bonus step:

5. Don't invite anyone to your private game.  And reject/ignore any join requests you get.

Comment: I actually figured that out my self but thanks. Upvote and selected. He he he. Yes it should have been obvious. I just "forget". Also in old interface I think there is "create game" option. I forget either.